# Java Hindi locale support?

Tags: java

I am using Java6 for my web application i am trying below code to change the laguage of my application

```
public static void doChangeLanguage(String argLang) {
        SessionValidationInitiator.setLanguage(argLang);
        LOGGER.debug("Changing Language to ... " + argLang);
        if(argLang.equalsIgnoreCase("fr_ca")){
        Locales.setThreadLocal(Locales.getLocale(Locale.FRENCH));
        Executions.getCurrent().getSession().setAttribute(Attributes.PREFERRED_LOCALE, Locale.FRENCH);
        Labels.reset();
        }else{
            Locales.setThreadLocal(Locales.getLocale(Locale.US));
            Executions.getCurrent().getSession().setAttribute(Attributes.PREFERRED_LOCALE, Locale.US);
            Labels.reset();
        }
        Executions.sendRedirect(null);
    }
```

Its working fine but when i am trying to change the Hindi i saw no any locale for indian language.

Can we support Hindi Locale as well from Java so that my application work for Hindi Language.

Comment: [JDK 7 and JRE 7 Supported Locales](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javase7locales-334809.html) suggests that `hi_IN` is Hindi. Given the absolute ease in which I found that info, you get a down-vote for me for lack of research.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Java 6 definitely has Hindi Locale support, refer to [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/locales-137662.html).

To explicitly set the locale to *Hindi, India* do something like this:

```
System.out.println(new Locale("hi", "IN"));
```

Prints;

```
hi_IN
```

The thing to note here is [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) does also offer constructors to accurately get a handle on the supported Locale(s) and variants.

Hence, in your code you might probably want to try out:

```
 Locales.setThreadLocal(Locales.getLocale(new Locale("hi", "IN")));
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 6 you need this: `Locale lc = new Locale("hi", "IN");`