# How to change Language on Android google map V2 api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I tried many ways to change language in google maps on android. It's not working.I tried to Change the locale of device with programming,also Force changed the locale of device. What should i do

Im using 
**com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0**

thank you

Comment: You can try to change `Locale.setDefault` as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638148/how-to-change-google-map-v2-language-for-android-app). Also, you can refer to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863288/how-to-change-language-google-map-v2-android)

Comment: Glad to help, I post an answer. You can accept if that helps you, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discuss in the comment: You can change `Locale.setDefault`.

Sample code:

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("ja"));
```

For more details, Please refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638148/how-to-change-google-map-v2-language-for-android-app) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863288/how-to-change-language-google-map-v2-android).